# Issues in loading a .glb file in a web worker offscreencanvas using Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have been trying to use GLTFLoader from Three.js to load a model into an offScreenCanvas. This is what I am currently trying:

```
import { DRACOLoader } from "three/examples/jsm/loaders/DRACOLoader";
import { GLTFLoader } from "three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader";
const loader = new GLTFLoader();
const draco = new DRACOLoader();
draco.setDecoderConfig({ type: "js" });
draco.setDecoderPath("https://www.gstatic.com/draco/v1/decoders/");

loader.setDRACOLoader(draco);

const res = await fetch("https://static.motionmix.ai/web/female.glb");
  if (!res.ok) return;
  const arrayBuffer = await res.arrayBuffer();
  loader.parse(
    arrayBuffer,
    "",
    (gltf) => {
      console.log("gltf loaded is", gltf);
    },
    (error) => {
      console.log("error", error);
    }
  );
```

Neither the onload nor the onerror callback gets triggered. I am very new to using web workers in javascript. But I am completely at a loss here.

I have tried to use loader.load as well, but to no avail. it seems like the callbacks just won’t get called. Where am I going wrong?